# How to parse a UTC date?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two strings timestamp and an UTC offset.

```
"timestamp":"2014-03-18T06:40:40+00:00","utc_offset":"+02:00"
```

I am trying to find a way to use these two to parse and create a UTC date.

I am able to parse the timestamp to DateTime, but not find help from the standard DateTime classes to parse the utc_offset and couldn't add the offset to the timestamp.

Without going to String manipulation, is there a standard way to handle this?

Comment: So you are not willing to replace the last 5 characters in the timestamp string with the value in utc_offset?

Comment: Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351654%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ?

Comment: Parse the timestamp as `DateTime` in UTC and then parse the offset as `TimeSpan` and combine them into a `DateTimeOffset`. Using `DateTime` instead of `DateTimeOffset` to represent times with a specific offset is a bad idea IMO.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I don't think it's such a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to create a `TimeSpan` object and add it to your `DateTime`.

```
TimeSpan tspan = TimeSpan.Parse("-02:00");
Console.WriteLine(tspan);   //This will print -02:00:00
```

See the following answer on how to convert an offset string ("+02:00") to a `TimeSpan`:

[How to convert string offset to timespan in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292805/how-to-convert-string-offset-to-timespan-in-c-sharp)

**EDIT: Please note that if you have the character `'+'` in your offset string, you will have to remove it before performing `TimeSpan.Parse("offsetString")`. This is the only string manipulation required. A negative offset requires the `'-'` character, but that should be obvious.**

Comment: Your code throws 'String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.' FormatException.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov If the offset string contains a `+` that will have to be removed first. But `-` works fine. If you don't remove the `+`, then yes this error will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of any good way to do it outside of string manipulation or the timespan one done by PaulG

```
string timestamp = "2014-03-18T06:40:40+00:00";
string utc_offset = "+02:00";

// Remove everything at the end beginning with the +
string complete = timestamp.Remove(timestamp.LastIndexOf('+')) + utc_offset;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression and `DateTime.TryParse` you could first replace the offset part og the date and then parse it into a `DateTime`,

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\+.+$");
var withOffset = regex.Replace("2014-03-18T06:40:40+00:00", "+02:00");

DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParse(withOffset, out date);
```

Alternatively, you could use `TimeSpan.TryParse` (like @PaulG metnions) to arrive to the same answer,

```
DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParse("2014-03-18T06:40:40+00:00", out date);
TimeSpan span;
TimeSpan.TryParse("+02:00", out span);
date.Add(span);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it

```
string timestampString = "2014-03-18T06:40:40+00:00";
DateTimeOffset timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Parse(timestampString);
string utcOffsetString = "+02:00";
DateTimeOffset utcOffset = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(utcOffsetString, "zzz", null);
DateTime fullDate = timestamp.UtcDateTime.Add(utcOffset.Offset);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string sNoOffset = "2014-03-18T06:40:40";

DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(sNoOffset);

TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(s);//where s is the offset

dt = dt.AddTicks(ts.Ticks);

MessageBox.Show(dt.ToString());

// Please customize the above lines of code to your liking.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, you might consider [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org). It has a small learning curve, but it is almost always worth it!

Here's how you would do this with Noda Time:

- First, create some patterns.  If you like, you can keep static instances of these for better performance on re-use.

  ```
  OffsetDateTimePattern tsPattern = OffsetDateTimePattern.GeneralIsoPattern;
  OffsetPattern offsetPattern = OffsetPattern.GeneralInvariantPattern;
  ```
- Use those patterns to parse the values you have into their appropriate Noda Time data types.  (You might also consider `Instant` for your timespan, but only if you know for certain that you will always be receiving it with an offset of all zeros.  Normally, you would see a `Z` there instead).

  ```
  OffsetDateTime timestamp = tsPattern.Parse("2014-03-18T06:40:40+00:00").Value;
  Offset offset = offsetPattern.Parse("+02:00").Value;
  ```
- Finally, you can apply the offset to your timestamp

  ```
  OffsetDateTime result = timestamp.ToInstant().WithOffset(offset);
  ```